# Error about something only supporting NHWC, but I am using NHWC

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I am getting a graph execution error. At the bottom it says 'Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC', but my input is in the format of NHWC. I am using the model.fit function, my model summary works, but as soon as .fit starts it shows this error. I can post my code and/or elaborate more, but I am very confused on what the error is.

Comment: Hi @Sankalp, the problem is with the data format of the model. It looks like a Conv2D layer should be using NHWC format (data_format="channels_last").

Comment: Please add some detailed error screenshots